# What does it mean to "take the mickey out of" something?

Tags: british-english

I am a Yank.  I have a friend who lives in the UK, in Sussex.  She writes:

> Mike and Rose are pretty good, but they tend to take the mickey out of
>   my inadequacies.

Mike and Rose are her children, BTW, and she's talking about her perceived inadequacies dealing with computers.

What on earth does it mean to "take the mickey out of" something?

Comment: [Taking the Mickey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taking_the_piss) (Mickey Bliss, Cockney rhyming slang) or taking the Michael is another term for making fun of someone.

Comment: I should point it's a phrase in its own right and people do not necessarily associate it with being cockney rhyming slang for a rude word. (I certainly didn't know it was rhyming slang until I saw @FumbleFingers's comment). Hence I wouldn't expect people to find it offensive in any way.

Comment: That is the polite form of taking the piss. Yes, to make fun of.

Comment: Oh, welcome back. Long time no see!

Comment: Thank you, @Mari-LouA, it is kind of you to notice my absence!  My wife passed away back in September, and I've pretty much been hibernating since then.  Only just starting to crawl out from under my rock, not to mix any metaphors.  So, I'm back among friends!

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry to hear that. My deepest most heart-felt condolences. Well, it's nice to see you back :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Taking the Mickey*
>
> Tease or make fun of.

It's a slang phrase, used primarily for jovial mockery, it's often light hearted.

[Source: Phrases.org.uk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/344000.html)