# Which Michael do the Scots want to take?

Tags: scottish-english

[In this clip of Dragon Den](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DF01t5HxizE&t=2764) you can hear [Duncan Bannatyne, a Scottish Torry Thatcherite, say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duncan_Bannatyne)

> You're taking the Michael, Anne

Specifically what "Michael" is Duncan taking? I can't find any information about him and why Duncan would want to speak of taking a lad on a major TV show.

Comment: Not sure Bannatyne's political persuasion is relevant but it's the same as taking the Mickey. Does this answer your question? [What does it mean to "take the mickey out of" something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302465/what-does-it-mean-to-take-the-mickey-out-of-something)

Comment: Torry is part of Aberdeen, Bannatyne is from Glasgow. Conservatives are 'Tories', one 'r'.

Comment: The question has been seen as a duplicate of “taking the mickey”. But previous answers dealing with that do not deal with the implications of using “Michael” rather than “mickey”. Therefore leave open for someone to deal with that point.

Answer (score 6):

> You're taking the Michael, Anne

It is not "Scottish English" - it is British English.

This is a mildly humorous variation on an idiom "to take the mickey [out of someone or something.]" = To mock someone/something mildly and humorously.

It is humorous because the name **Mickey** is an affectionate version of the name **Michael/Mike**.

OED:

> **mickey**
>
> **7.** colloquial (chiefly British). **to take the mickey (out of): to behave or speak satirically or mockingly; to make fun of, satirize, or debunk (a person or thing). Cf. mike n.7 <sup>1</sup>, piss n. 2.**
>
> 1948   A. Baron From City, from Plough vi. 49   ‘Higgsy,’ said the sergeant, ‘they think I'm taking the mickey. Tell 'em.’
>
> 1952   ‘J. Henry’ Who lie in Gaol iv. 66   She's a terror. I expect she'll try and take the mickey out of you all right. Don't you stand for nothin'.
>
> 1991   Sunday Sun (Brisbane) 3 Feb. 6/5   I don't think there is any subject that is too serious to take the micky out of.

The origin, which few people are aware of, is probably from rhyming slang:

> **<sup>1</sup> mike**, n.7
>
> **Etymology**: Origin uncertain; **perhaps after Mike Bliss**, rhyming slang (listed in J. Franklyn Dict. **Rhyming Slang (ed. 2, 1961) 158) for piss** (see to take the piss (out of) at piss n. Phrases 2b).
>
> Only in *to take the mike out of*: = to take the mickey (out of) at mickey n.1 7.
>
> *Not found in North America*.
>
> a1935   T. E. Lawrence Mint (1955) ii. vi. 117   *But, mate, you let the flight down, when he takes the mike out of you every time.*

Edit to add:

The chronological progression of this version of the idiom thus seems to be

to take the piss [out of someone/something] (still extant)

to take the Mike Bliss [out of someone/something] (no longer used)

to take the Mike [out of someone/something] (no longer used)

to take the Mickey [out of someone/something] (not used)

to take the mickey [out of someone/something] (still extant)

to take the mike [out of someone/something] (no longer used)

to take the Michael [out of someone/something] (The use recently coined)